# Unlock iPhone X simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-x

I have been having a hard time to unlock the iPhone X in simulator.When trying to unlock it says Swipe up to unlock, that's it. Nothing happens when i swipe up, any idea how to unlock ?

Comment: Swipe up from the bottom like you would on a real iPhone X.

Comment: Swipe up to unlock : This works for me , you have to drag it from bottom of the screen

Comment: see this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/90378

Comment: Command + shift + H to unlock any iPhone simulator from keyboard

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Press

```
Command + Shift + H.
```

It will work for all the simulators.

Answer (score 5):

Press 'Command + Shift + H' twice to unlock it

Answer (score 3):

You can unlock iPhone X simulator like this

[image]

Comment: doesn't work, might be bug as someone mentioned in the comments